# API used to call receiver app in VideoBrowserActivity

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

As all of know that Google has launched new APIs for Chrome-Cast which are public.

So while developing it for an android, they have given some sample codes on Github.

While reading [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) of android app, they have clearly mentioned that to launch receiver file on Chrome-Cast we need to create `GoogleApiClient` and then we can connect to it.

But the sample app uploaded over [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android), is not calling APIs regarding launching Receiver app and creating Client (or maybe I am not aware of of APIs are being used to call receiver file). So I am facing trouble to write my own app. So can anybody tell where this part is being carried out or can anybody can give me another way to do it and explain me the workflow of that app??

**NOTE: I WANT TO DO IT FOR VIDEOS**

Answer (score 0):

The sample app uses the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android), which

> is a library project to enable developers integrate Cast capabilities into their applications faster and easier.

Comment: So you mean to say if app using CCL (CastCompanionLibrary) no need to create client,Launch Receiver app and Create communication Channel??

Comment: I haven't looked into the sample app or the CCL myself, but I recommend to look into the documentation of CCL to get a clue how the sample app works: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/CastCompanionLibrary.pdf .
I guess the CCL does things like handle boilerplate client/receiver/communication code.

Comment: CCL does that for you, there is no magic there. Read the documentation on CCL.